# Work out distance moved from mousedown in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to get translation x and translation y value through mouse move event in jquery.

when am mouse down the particular point in the page and the moving the cursor i need to find the translation values how much distance it moved from old point to new point. same am moving again means need to calculate how much distance it moved from previous old point to new point.

that means need to calculate the translateX and translatY. but e contains something pageX,clientX like that there is no translateX / translateY in jquery ?

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: If you know of Pythagoras Theorem, you can use that. I do hope your not expecting a block of code from someone.

Comment: how can i do this in jquery ? any idea

Comment: StackOverflow is not a bespoke service where you tell the community what you want and we develop code for you. Demonstrate that you have at least made an effort by showing the code you've written so far and we'll help you sort out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var bMouseDown = false;
var oPreviousCoords = {
    'x': 0,
    'y': 0
}

$(document).on('mousedown', function (oEvent) {
    bMouseDown = true;
    oPreviousCoords = {
        'x': oEvent.pageX,
        'y': oEvent.pageY
    }
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function (oEvent) {
    bMouseDown = false;
});

$(document).on('mousemove', function (oEvent) {
    var oDelta;

    if (!bMouseDown) {
        return;
    }

    oDelta = {
        'x': oPreviousCoords.x - oEvent.pageX,
        'y': oPreviousCoords.y - oEvent.pageY
    }

    oPreviousCoords = {
        'x': oEvent.pageX,
        'y': oEvent.pageY
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think you'll need to store the current values in a couple of variables then compare the next time the mousemove event is fired, something like this:

```
var transX = 0;
var transY = 0;
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    if (e.pageX>transX)
    {
        transX = transX-e.pageX;
    }
    else 
    {
        transX = e.pageX-transX;
    }
    //and the same for transY
});
```

As far as I know there isn't a transY or transX property in javascript for a mousemove event.